# Windows 8 VMWare guest under Ubuntu 16.04 host doesn't have access to the internet

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware, nat, vmware-player

I have `Ubuntu 16.04` host machine with `WMWare Player` and `Windows 8` guest. The problem is that the guest Windows machine doesn't have access to the internet.

**Host Ubuntu 16.04 configuration**:

```
>>> grep VERSION= /etc/*-release 
/etc/os-release:VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

[image]

```
>>> sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

>>> sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

**VMWare configuration**:

```
> vmware --version
VMware Workstation 12.1.0 build-3272444
```

[image: virtual network editor]
[image: vm network configuration]

**Windows guest machine**:

[image: windows version]
[image]
[image: windows ipconfig]

**Testing**:
[image]
[image]

**Notes**:

- Note the `ping` is ok and `nslookup` hangs. Looks like host machine is stopping the traffic.
- I tried `ssh` into host - ok.
- I tried `ssh` into other machine within the Local `lo` network of the host - ok
- The gateway in the network config is set to `172.16.223.2`. I tried to change that to the IP of the host (`172.16.223.1`) - same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My case was really simple. For some reason `VMWare` hasn't picked up proper `DNS`'s of the host and `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` are blocked within the internal network. Setting `DNS` servers manually within `Windows` to the IPs that are allowed within internal network fixed the issue.

I am marking the question as resolved, but if smb posts a solution to fix the `VMWare` to pick-up the `DNS`'s of the host, I will switch to his answer.